# Issues with Stripe Integration and Third-Party Cookies - Node.js/Express/React

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, stripe-payments

[Console warning screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56Ipq.png) I am working on an e-commerce application using Node.js, Express, and React. I have integrated Stripe for payment processing. However, I am facing a couple of issues that I need assistance with:
Third-Party Cookie Warning:
I am encountering warnings in the console related to third-party cookies. The message states, "Third-party cookie will be blocked. Learn more in the Issues tab." I understand that this is related to changes in browser behavior, but I'm unsure how to address it.

Frontend side code

```
 const handleSaveShippingInfo = async () => {
    try {
      const stripe = await loadStripe('publishable_key');
      console.log('Shipping Info:', shippingInfo);
      console.log(products);
  
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/orders/place-order', {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ shippingInfo, products }),
      });
  
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
      }
  
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
      const result = stripe.redirectToCheckout({sessionId:session.id})
      if(result.error){
        console.log(result.error)
      }

      // Close the modal after saving shipping info
      onRequestClose()
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error.message);
    }
  };
```

Backend side code :

```
    orderRouter.post("/place-order", isAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    let totalPrice = 0;
    try {
    const { shippingInfo, products } = req.body;
    for (const product of products) {
      // used for of loop to iterate over the products object usme jo value hai
      const productId = await product.product;       console.log(productId);

      const singleProduct = await Products.findById(productId);
      // console.log(req.user._id)
      const productPrice = product.quantity * singleProduct.price;
      totalPrice += productPrice;
      const c = await Cart.findOneAndDelete({productId:productId,userId:req.user._id})
      console.log(c)`enter code here`
    }

    const lineItems = products.map((product)=>({
      price_data:{
        currency:'usd',
        product_data:{
          id:product.product
        },unit_amount:totalPrice*100,
      },quantity:product.quantity 
    }))
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      payment_method_types:['card'],
      line_items:lineItems,
      mode:'payment',success_url:"http://localhost:5173/success",
      cancel_url:"http://localhost:5173/cancel"
    })

    const order = await Orders.create({
      shippingInfo,
      products,
      user: req.user._id,
      totalPrice,
    });

    
    res.status(201).json({ order ,id:session.id });
  
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send("Internal Sever Error");
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the console warnings? Is Stripe causing these warnings to appear? Also, can you still process a payment, or is some functionality broken?

Comment: after clicking on submit button the Stripe warning comes,but the security warning is there even when I open it in development mode